# Greedy knapsack algorithm

Tags: python, knapsack-problem, greedy

The task is classic knapsack problem. Greedy algorithm should be used in solvation. I managed to create code below, but it works too slow. Could you give me an idea how to speed it up? Thank you.

```
def backpack(c, array):
    array.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    array.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
    backpack = []

    for item in array:
        if item[1] <= c:
            backpack.append(item)
            c -= item[1]

    result = []
    for item in backpack:
        result.append(item[2])
    result.sort()

    return print(*result)


c = int(input())
n = int(input())
array = list()
for i in range(n):
    item = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    array.append(item)
    array[i].append(i)

backpack(c, array)
```

c is weight limit for backpack. n represents the amount of price-weight pairs (both numbers have int type, not float). Restrictions are following: 1) should you choose between elements with the same weight, the one with the highest price should be taken 2) should you choose between elements with the same price and same weight, the one which was inputed first should be taken.

Comment: What is `c`? Give the sample  values for your `array` and in what format the values are stored in the array. Also explain what is the criterion for filling the backpack?

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: What's your expected output i.e the return value of `backpack` function?

Comment: indexes of price-weight pairs which were taken to backpack. given pairs: 1-2, 2-2, 3-3 and weight limit of 2 we need to output 1.

Answer (score 1):

We can use:

```
def backpack(weight, arr):
    # Associate the index with each pair of the given array.
    arr = [(idx, pair) for idx, pair in enumerate(arr)]

    # sort the arr in descending order with highest price taking precedence
    arr = sorted(arr, reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1][0]) 

    result, totalWeight = [], 0
    for item in arr:
        if item[1][1] + totalWeight <= weight:
            totalWeight += item[1][1] # increase the cummalative weight of backpack

            result.append(item[0]) # Append the index of added pair to result
    return result
```

---

Example:

```
# arr contains the pairs of <price, weight>
arr = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 1], [2, 4], [2, 3], [5, 1], [1, 5], [3, 3], [2, 2]]
weight = 7
print(backpack(weight, arr))
```

Result:

```
[5, 7, 1] # indices of pairs in arr which are taken from array and added to backpack
```

Comment: unfortunately it gives wrong answer and since I can't access test cases, I can not say why exactly. Tested all corner cases myself and your code seems to be working properly.

Comment: Well, yes it should work fine.  Any informative message regarding why your test platform is not passing the answer?

Comment: unfortunately no, in my school I can only see the error code and that's it. Thank you very much for your help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
def backpack(c, array):
    array.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
    print(array)
    result = 0
    for item in array:
        if c-item[1] >= 0:
            c=c-item[1]
            result=result+item[0]
        else:
            fraction = c/float(item[1])
            print(fraction)
            result+=(item[0]*fraction)
            break

    return result


c = int(input())
n = int(input())
array = []
for i in range(n):
    item = tuple(int(x) for x in raw_input().split())
    array.append(item+(item[0]//item[1],))
backpack(c, array)
```